# Android: Does DateFormat.format("KK:mm"...) work well anywhere?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to show start and end time of the calendar events in my app and I use this codes:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;
```

and

```
private void populateList() {
     
    eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(EventListConst.FIRST_COLUMN, "Begin");
    temp.put(EventListConst.SECOND_COLUMN, "End");
    temp.put(EventListConst.THIRD_COLUMN, "Title");
    
    eventsList.add(temp);
    
    EventCursor ec = getEvents();
    if(ec==null)
        return;
    
    Calendar eventCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    while(ec!=null && ec.moveToNext()){
        
        Event e = ec.getEvent();
        eventCalendar.setTimeInMillis(e.begin);                     
        temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(EventListConst.FIRST_COLUMN, DateFormat.format("KK:mm", eventCalendar.getTime()).toString());
        eventCalendar.setTimeInMillis(e.end);
        temp.put(EventListConst.SECOND_COLUMN,DateFormat.format("KK:mm", eventCalendar.getTime()).toString());
        temp.put(EventListConst.THIRD_COLUMN, e.title);
        eventsList.add(temp);
    }
    
    EventsListViewAdapter adapter = new EventsListViewAdapter(this, eventsList);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The time, in my application to be displayed like it:

> Begin      End
>
> KK:45      KK:00

But the minutes displayed correctly.

---

#### Solved

I have changed my codes and my app works well.

```
while(ec!=null && ec.moveToNext()){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Event e = ec.getEvent();
        eventCalendar.setTimeInMillis(e.begin);                     
        temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(EventListConst.FIRST_COLUMN, dateFormat.format( eventCalendar.getTime()).toString());
        eventCalendar.setTimeInMillis(e.end);
        temp.put(EventListConst.SECOND_COLUMN,dateFormat.format( eventCalendar.getTime()).toString());
        temp.put(EventListConst.THIRD_COLUMN, e.title);
        eventsList.add(temp);
    }
```

Comment: replace "KK" with "HH"

Comment: Where is `DateFormat` declared? I'm surprised that code even compiles unless you've got a variable called `DateFormat` somewhere. (You'd normally create an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` with the pattern, and then call `format` on that.)

Comment: @Salmaan I did it but I got the same error "HH:45"

Comment: @JonSkeet
thank you but why the minutes compiles without error? if you want I can write the full code here

Comment: @JonSkeet
Thanks man
I declared `SimpleDateFormat` and my problem solved...